# Is it possible to import data to multiple tables from one excel sheet using laravel excel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

We are creating an application were a user can upload an excel file that contains information for multiple tables. (See screenshot below for example). Is it possible to split this data up and create multiple models to be imported into a database using laravel excel? If not, is there another package that you'd recommend using?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from my understanding you can only have one model per import in the controller.

Controller:

```
class ImportsController
{
    public function import()
    {
        Excel::import(new DataImport, 'testSheet.xlsx'); //only allows for one model

        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');
    }
}
```

Import:

```
class DataImport implements ToModel
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        // need way to create and return multiple models
        return new Data([

        ]);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/import', 'ImportsController@import');
```

[image: First row is table name, second row is field name, all following rows are data]

First row is table name, second row is field name, all following rows are data

Comment: The answer is yes. You can treat the data anyway you want once it's extracted from the excel. You can use as many models as you want in a controller. It just depends in how you use them.

Comment: @Indra thank you for your response. Sorry I'm pretty new to laravel and php.  Could you provide an example on how you might do this? I've edited the question above to include a bit more information. 
From my understanding, the "model" function in the DataImport usually returns one model that is created in that function. After that model is returned, the import method takes it and imports it to the database. So how would you create multiple models by reading in the table row in the excel sheet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of importing to a model, you could import to a collection, and create two models on each row:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\EmployeeType;
use App\Contact;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class EmployeesImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            EmployeeType::create([
                'name' => $row[1],
            ]);

            Contact::create([
                'institution' => $row[3],
                'type' => $row[4],
                'address' => $row[5],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/imports/collection.html)

It is possible to import multiple sheets at once with multiple imports by using the [WithMultipleSheets](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html) concern, but as far as I know you can not use this to create multiple imports from a single sheet.

Comment: I'm afraid that using `toCollection` interface and calling `create` method like this will do insert query for each row which might not what we want. Whereas using `toModel` interface along with `withBatchInserts` will insert all at once. Unfortunately `withBatchInserts` does not work with `toCollection`.

Comment: Can you get the id of each EmployeeType and use in Contact table?

Comment: @Mahdi Yes, the `create` method returns the stored model instance, so you could save it in a variable `$employeeType = EmployeeType::create(...);`, and use `$employeeType->id` when creating the Contact.